# Execute code in the middle of two jQuery animations?

Tags: jquery, animation

i have the following code which switches some fullscreen-background-images (fadeOut, fadeIn).

```
setInterval(function() { 
        var id = parseInt($('img.active').attr('id').substring(3,4));
        var id_next = id;
        switch(id) {
            case 0:
                id_next = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                id_next = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                id_next = 0;
                break;
        }
        $('img.active').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('img#bg_' + id).removeClass('active');
            $('div.start-headline h1').html(hl[id]);
            $('div.start-headline h2').html(sl[id]);
        });
        $('img#bg_' + id_next).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                $('img#bg_' + id_next).addClass('active');
                $('div.start-switches div').removeClass('active');
                $('div.start-switches div#' + id).addClass('active');
            });
    }, 6000);
```

how can i tell this code, that it should execute these two lines

```
$('div.start-headline h1').html(hl[id]);
$('div.start-headline h2').html(sl[id]);
```

in the middle of the two fades? now it executes after the images faded...

thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to do it just after the fadeout is over and the fadein is about to begin?

Comment: right in the middle when the fade out is completed and the fade in starts, yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to queue it, so it runs fadeOut -> new queued -> fadeIn

```
$('img.active').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('img#bg_' + id).removeClass('active');
});
$('img.active').queue(function() {
    $('div.start-headline h1').html(hl[id]);
    $('div.start-headline h2').html(sl[id]);
    $(this).dequeue();
});
$('img#bg_' + id_next).fadeIn('slow', function() {
    $('img#bg_' + id_next).addClass('active');
    $('div.start-switches div').removeClass('active');
    $('div.start-switches div#' + id).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the problem I think you just need to put the

```
 $('img#bg_' + id_next).fadeIn('slow', function() {
            $('img#bg_' + id_next).addClass('active');
            $('div.start-switches div').removeClass('active');
            $('div.start-switches div#' + id).addClass('active');
        });
```

into the callback just afther the  `$('img#bg_' + id).removeClass('active');`

If I don't understood well the problem, please can you specify when the code is execude (if while the fadein or after) so maybe I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out roughly how long the "slow" animation is for fade out and add like 100 milliseconds, use that time in a delay. Put the delay code outside of the fade out

```
$('div.start-headline h1').delay(fadeout_time+100).html(hl[id]);
```

I dunno if the delay would affect the animation or not but you can test it out and see if it works. I think you can also set another time interval with relations to the one you already have to manipulate the html